# Elasticsearch filter documents with date in epoch format

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents in `ES` contain a field that stores date value in `epoch` format like this:

`"received": 1521055535062`

I am trying to build a query where I can filter documents based on a certain date with or without UTC time difference taken into account.

Since I have over a million records in `ES`, I would like a way to figure out how many of those documents belonged to a specific date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the date range query with date format specification that you want. The following should return the docs received on first day of 2018

```
GET _search
{
 "query": {
    "range" : {
        "received" : {
            "gte": "01/01/2018",
            "lt": "01/02/2018",
            "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
        }
    }
 }
}
```

See here for the details https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a snippet of Java code (using the range query). From the question, it's not clear in which language the query should be written but if it's in Java, following snippet should be helpful:

```
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        Date asOfDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - historySeconds * 1000);
        boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("created").from(asOfDate).includeLower(true));
```

Comment: Upvoted for you. I should have been more specific :)